# How to count substring instances in a exchange body

Tags: apache-camel

I have a body consisting of something like: OK,OK,NOK,OK,NOK, using Spring DSL.
I want to count the instances of substring 'OK' in the body. I tried StringHelper countChar, but you can only pass it chars.

Is there a way to count substrings in a body without resorting to java beans?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *bean* to invoke an static method, such *org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.countMatches* to get the number of matches in the body:

```
from("direct:source")
    .bean(StringUtils.class, "countMatches(${body}, OK)")
    .to("log:org.orzowei.so.question.q69134695?level=WARN")
    .end();
```

Or using Spring DSL:

```
<route id="abcRoute" autoStartup="true">
  <from uri="direct:source"/>
  <bean beanType="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" method="countMatches(${body}, OK)"/>
  <to uri="log:org.orzowei.so.question.q69134695?level=WARN"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time t awnser, but I'm looking for a solution in Spring DSL (XML Format)